# Ramda recursive curried function throws Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming, ramda.js, currying

I try to understand ramda a bit better and why in the following example `mapTreeNode2` does not work exactly like `mapTreeNode`.

In a new project my state is represented in a huge tree and I want to make sure I get the fundamentals of immutable tree manipulation with ramda right.

```js
const state = {
  id: 1,
  name: "first",
  children: [{
    id: 2,
    name: "second",
    children: []
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: "third",
    children: [{
      id: 4,
      name: "fourth",
      children: []
    }]
  }, {
    id: 5,
    name: "fifth",
    children: [{
      id: 6,
      name: "sixth",
      children: []
    }]
  }]
};

 
const hasChildren = (node) => {
  var x = 
     (typeof node === 'object')
        && (typeof node.children !== 'undefined')
        && (node.children.length > 0);

  // console.log(x, node) 
  
  return x
} 

// This works
const mapTreeNode = curry( (mapFn, treeNode) => {
        const newTreeNode = mapFn(treeNode);
        if (!hasChildren(treeNode)) {
            return newTreeNode;
        }
        return evolve({children: map(mapTreeNode(mapFn))}, newTreeNode)
    })

// This doesn't: Maximum call stack size exceeded
const mapTreeNode2 = curry( (mapFn) => ifElse(
  hasChildren,
  compose(
    evolve({children: map(mapTreeNode2(doStuff))}), 
    mapFn,
  ), 
  mapFn
))
 

const doStuff = ifElse(propEq('id', 6), evolve({name: concat("x")}), identity)

// This works
mapTreeNode(doStuff)(state)

// This doesn't: Maximum call stack size exceeded
mapTreeNode2(doStuff)(state)
```

Comment: AFAICT (didn't read the code super carefully) short answer is because ramda's curry [uses arity checking](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/171b34e9d3b38111bf3d909bf2f0e1467c6a5053/source/curry.js#L66)(note the check on the function argument's `.length` property), and you're passing an arity-1 function in the second example. It will recurse endlessly on the first call `mapTreeNode2(doStuff)` and never reach the second `(state)`. Point-free style is nice and all, but not sure it really gains you that much here (or in general really).

Comment: Surely you mean `evolve({children: map(mapTreeNode2(mapFn))})` not `evolve({children: map(mapTreeNode2(doStuff))})`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any `curry`ing here since the function has only a single parameter anyway. But that's not the issue, it doesn't work without `curry` either. To see why, let's refactor the function a bit:

```
const mapTreeNode2 = (mapFn) => {
  const mapper = mapTreeNode2(mapFn);
  const evolver = evolve({children: map(mapper)});
  const then = compose(evolver, mapFn);
  return ifElse(hasChildren, then, mapFn);
};
```

Right there in the first line we have an unbounded recursion… The problem is that JS is using strict evaluation, so the code of the `then` branch still gets evaluated with `ifElse`, unlike a proper `if`/`else` statement or conditional operator expression.

To avoid that, you can try

```
const mapTreeNode2 = (mapFn) => {
  const evolver = evolve({children: map(mapper)});
  const then = compose(evolver, mapFn);
  const mapper = ifElse(hasChildren, then, mapFn);
  return mapper;
};
```

but again that won't work without lazy evaluation, accessing `mapper` in the temporal dead zone. The only way to resolve this circular reference between variables in JS is to use a function and utilise hoisting, e.g.

```
const mapTreeNode2 = (mapFn) => {
  const mapper = (treeNode) => {
    const evolver = evolve({children: map(mapper)});
//                                        ^^^^^^ now the reference works
    const then = (node) => compose(evolver, mapFn);
    return ifElse(hasChildren, then, mapFn)(treeNode);
  };
  return mapper;
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Bergi for the explanation. I found a way to make `mapTreeNode2` work - which might be similar to your solution. Could you comment on if that is the right use of currying or if it is unnecessary? ```const mapTreeNode2 = curry( (mapFn, obj) => ifElse(
  hasChildren,
  compose(
    evolve({children: map(mapTreeNode2(doStuff))}), 
    mapFn,
  ), 
  mapFn
)(obj))
```

Comment: Yeah, that works as well, it's basically the same as your already-working solution with `if`/`else`. Except that you should use `mapFn` instead of `doStuff` in the recursive call!